# Pass state as prop with a single line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below code doesn't work, it has error, just curious how to show another component like modal?

```
showModal(){
    this.setState({preview:true})
    <Modal show={this.state.preview} />
}
```

I felt it's redundant to set the `preview` to true and then pass it to show prop. Since I have declare defaultProps in Modal component, the show is by default false, I doubt whether I still need to set a state `preview` to false in initialState in component that will call the `Modal`.

Comment: What is the exact error? I feel you would also need to `return <Modal />` if you're calling that method as part of your `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must *return* the Babel / HTML components you want to be rendered. This can be achieved by:

```
return (
   <Modal show={this.state.preview} />
);
```

Generally the way you would structure the code, is when you want to render something (i.e. after an event, button click, etc), is to then set the state when that happens, and then in the body that renders the `<Modal .. />` component, put an if condition in there checking for the state. e.g.:

```
showModal = () => {
    if(this.state.preview) {
        return (
            <Modal />
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <SampleComponent />
        { this.showModal() }
    );
}
```

You try not to pass states that control visibility to components like that. You control visibility of the component in the parent.